# sql server database column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three columns in my table.

```
+---------+---------+--------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column |
+---------+---------+--------+
| A       | H       | UC     |
| B       | G       | UC     |
| C       | F       | UC     |
| D       | Q       | UC     |
| A       | S       | UC     |
| B       | D       | UC     |
| C       | G       | UC     |
| D       | z       |        |
+---------+---------+--------+
```

Input in procedure ABCD. The first time output should be HGFQ. The second time should be SDGZ.

The third column is for upper case\lower care\numbers.

It match I replace it continuously.

Comment: This post does not contain a question.

Comment: Very hard to understand what you are trying to do and you don't really ask a question. Post your query and clarify what you want for results.

Comment: What you actually looking for?

Comment: Can you _please_ format the query?

Answer (score 0):

> Input in procedure ABCD . first time output should be HGFQ.Second time
>   it should be SDGZ

looks like you want use [`FETCH .. OFFSET`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx#Example) construct like

```
select column2
from tbl1
where column1 in ('A','B','C','D')
order by column2 offset 4 rows fetch next 4 rows only
```